# convert stream to audio file

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, multipartform-data

I send an audio file to a server API in MultiPartFormData. for this purpose, first, I convert storage File to Byte format, then I convert Byte to Stream and after that I post with MultiPartFormData request.That server answer my request in MultiPartformData format with an another Audio file too.
I receive that respond in HttpResponceMesseage, my question is how can I convert it to mp3 file?
I am using windows iot with UWP coding platform.

```
multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(await GetBytesAsync(storageFile)),"audio","audio.mp3");
request.Content = multipartContent;
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var content = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, if you want to write to a file using stream, we will following the four-step model:

1. [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync) the file to get a stream
2. [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream.getoutputstreamat) an output stream.
3. Create a [DataWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter) object and call the corresponding Write method.
4. [Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.storeasync) the data in the data writer and [flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ioutputstream.flushasync) the output stream.

Please see [Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#writing-to-a-file) and [Best practices for writing to files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/best-practices-for-writing-to-files) for more information.

The official [File access sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I done it with extra following code.
first, I convert response to byte[] array, then I write bytes to file within new task thread,that because of main thread correspond to UI won't let another Async task run on it.

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
byte[] x=await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
await Task.Run(() =>
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(storageFile.Path,x));
```